# C# CAS .Net Where is the proxy ticket?

Tags: c#, .net, cas

Using : https://github.com/apereo/dotnet-cas-client

We can successfully see a proxy ticket in the logs generated but when accessing the the field 'ProxyGrantingTicket' it's always empty.

```
ICasPrincipal p = HttpContext.Current.User;
p.ProxyGrantingTicket
```

We can see the ticket in the cache, but assumed there would be a method to access it.

---

This works but would like to know if theres an inbuilt fucntion for this.

```
    // Retrieves the cookie that contains your custom FormsAuthenticationTicket.
    var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    // Decrypts the FormsAuthenticationTicket that is held in the cookie's .Value property.
    var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

    var ticket = HttpContext.Current.Cache["CasTicket::" + authTicket.UserData] as CasAuthenticationTicket;


    ticket.ProxyGrantingTicket
```

Or slightly more streamlined way...

```
var formTicket = CasAuthentication.GetFormsAuthenticationTicket();

var ticket = CasAuthentication.ServiceTicketManager.GetTicket(formTicket.UserData);
```

Comment: Try tracing the location of the log statement in the .NET CAS Client library that is displaying the proxy ticket to find out where it's being accessed / stored?

Comment: Stored in the cache, but no obvious way to retrieve it for the user.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CAS. What do you mean by "the cache"? A library specific cache? The remote user's browser cache?

Comment: Sorry - HttpContext.Current.Cache

Answer (score 0):

Is `CasAuthentication.ProxyTicketManager.GetProxyGrantingTicket(string proxyGrantingTicketIou)` not working?